# what is different in Android 5.0 (LOLLIPOP) notification?

Tags: android

I have bunch of apps that use notifications work for Android 4.4 and lower. Are these notifications going to work in android 5.0? If not, how to set notifications in Android 5.0?

Comment: Don't Downvote, if you don't have to comment anything. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to change anything, only functionality is added.

---

[Android Lollipop - Notifications](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#Notifications):

> Notifications in Android 5.0 are more visible, accessible, and
>   configurable.
>
> Varying notification details may appear on the lock screen if desired
>   by the user. Users may elect to allow none, some, or all notification
>   content to be shown on a secure lock screen.
>
> Key notification alerts such as incoming calls appear in a heads-up
>   notification—a small floating window that allows the user to respond
>   or dismiss without leaving the current app.
>
> You can now add new metadata to notifications to collect associated
>   contacts (for ranking), category, and priority.
>
> A new media notification template provides consistent media controls
>   for notifications with up to 6 action buttons, including custom
>   controls such as "thumbs up"—no more need for RemoteViews!

Answer (score 0):

In android 5.0 (Lollipop) only functionality has increased.So Lollipop will support all lower API apps without fail.

Read more about Lollipop here - [Android Lollipop](http://www.queryhome.com/63766/android-lollipop-version-5-0)